# Cast to a C# object using remote PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, casting, remoting, wsman

I am connecting remotely to a PowerShell console using C#:

```
using (Runspace remoteRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(setUpConnection()))
{
    remoteRunspace.Open();
    using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        powershell.Runspace = remoteRunspace;

        DateTime dateTime = GetTime(powershell);  // <------ How to implement?
    }
    remoteRunspace.Close();
}
```

I want to call the [Get-Date](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849887.aspx) PowerShell command and somehow cast `PSObject` to `DateTime`. What is "the usual" way to solve this problem?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use the [PSObject.BaseObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psobject.baseobject%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property:

```
using (Runspace remoteRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(setUpConnection()))
{
    remoteRunspace.Open();
    using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        powershell.Runspace = remoteRunspace;

        DateTime dateTime = (DateTime)powershell.Invoke().Single().BaseObject;
    }
    // No need to close runspace; you are disposing it.
}
```